# How to check every item inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have an array of objects and render every item inside it in input and under this section, I have a button that does something

I want to check every item "input" if it's empty don't call a function pressed on the button

my code works for first object not all,

state

```
 toolsUsed: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: '..',
        price: '..',
        count: '..',
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: '..',
        price: '..',
        count: '..',
      },
      ...
    ],
]
```

here's my iterable array

```
renderToolsUsed = () => {
    const {toolsUsed} = this.state;

    return toolsUsed.map(({name, id, price, count}, i) => {
      console.log('i', i);
      if (
        toolsUsed[i].name.length > 0 &&
        toolsUsed[i].price.length > 0 &&
        toolsUsed[i].count.length > 0
      ) {
        this.setState({valid: true});
      }

      return(
         <View>.....</View>
      )
    }
```

Button function

```
 pressed = ()=>{
    if(this.state.vaild){
       call...
    }else{
        alert("please fill all fields");
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**

For answer @SLePort

```
renderToolsUsed = () => {
    const {toolsUsed} = this.state;

    return toolsUsed.map((item, i) => {
      console.log(item);
      this.setState(
        {
          // ...item,
          isValid: ['name', 'price', 'count'].every(
            key => item[key].length > 0,
          ),
        },
        () => console.log('isValid', this.state.isValid),
      );

       return (
        <View key={i} style={styles.tools}>
             <Text>{item.name}</Text>
             ...
        </View>
       );
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop on the items and add a `isValid` key if every property to check has a `length > 0`.

```
const toolsUsed = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'first',
    price: '2',
    count: '4',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'second',
    price: 1,
    count: 8,
  },
]

const validToolsUsed = toolsUsed.map(item => ({
    ...item, 
    isValid: ['name', 'price', 'count']
      .every(key => item[key].length > 0 )
  })
)
```

Comment: u mean to add it inside `setState`?

Comment: it's working fine when adding it inside `setState` but can u explain more, `...item,` what does mean and why are we doing it?  and `item[key]`? cuz when I log `item[key]` it returns undefined!

Comment: `...item` uses the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax to expand all entries of your object before adding the `isValid` property. The `key` refers to each key in `['name', 'price', 'count']`, the properties you want to check the value of.

Comment: well but I mean why add `key` inside `[  ]` ~`item[key]`~ in `every()` callback ? and i don't have any flag refer to the `item` inside `State` so i think i have something wrong?  check my Edit Section in Question

Comment: `item` and `key` both refers to the current value being processed in the array. They are just use in the callback and have nothing to do with your state. In `[1,2].map(e => e*2)`, `e` is just the variable that will be use on each item of the array to produce `[2,4]`. See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more.

Comment: It's not my cup of tea but he just asking why you do this `item[key].length` instead of `item[item.key].length` OR `item.key.length`

Comment: yeah exactly that's what I need to understand 

Comment: `item` is the object of `toolUsed` you loop on with `map`. `key` is the key of `[ 'name', 'price', 'count' ]` you loop on with `every`.  In this nested loop, `item[key]` is successively `item['name']`, `item['price']` and `item['count']`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing, it set's state for the first item only,
 After `setState` is called as it triggers re-render may be you are facing issue
 may be `Array.reduce` will help you

try this

```
 const isValid =  toolsUsed.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(curr.name.length && curr.price.length && curr.count.length) {
     return true
   }
   return false
   }, false
   )
this.setState({isValid })
```

If you have any codesandbox sample please share, so that the function can be optimised, please observe that the second paramenter of the reduce fuction will be the initial value of accumulator `acc`, may be you have to tweak it for your actual functionality to work

Please feel free to ask questions if any