# How to solve Cannot update during an existing state issue - react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function I calling it in render() method
and it's setState a Flag from the state.

So I got this error

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render`).

I read about this error, and what I understand it's because I setState in render method and this is the wrong way.

*So I'm forced to do it if u have any idea to handle this tell me.*

**The main idea about this function**

I have an array of an object "Name as *Tools*" so in every object I have "id, name, count, price" 
so that will render a three input in UI like this

[image: UI]

and I have a boolean flag in-state "isEmpty" that checks every input in array before sending this data to the database.

Code

```
State = {
   toolsUsed: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        price: '',
        count: '',
      },
    ],
    // Checker
    isEmpty: false,
}

renderToolsUsed = () => {
  const {toolsUsed} = this.state;
  const tools = toolsUsed.map((item, i) => {
  const {count, price, name, id} = item;
  this.setState({
     isEmpty: ['name', 'price', 'count'].every(key => item[key].length > 0),
   });
   return (
      <View key={i} style={styles.tools}>
         .... Inputs here ...
      </View>
   );
 });
 return tools;
};
```

JSX

```
render() {
    return (
       <View>
           {this.renderToolsUsed()}
       </View>
     );
}
```

Comment: What does `isEmpty` truly mean? Since you will have array of Tools. Shouldn't you have array of `isEmpty`? And why need `isEmpty` when you already have array of `toolsUsed`. You can use that to check if it is empty.

Comment: @invisal it adds a key for every item in a tool to check it if was empty or not 

Comment: can u check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437589/how-to-check-every-item-inside-array) @invisal

Comment: I feel like `isEmpty` in your case is referring to `isNotEmpty` ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can't update the state like this. It is like infinite loop. setState will trigger render, then render will trigger another setState, then you keep repeat the circle.

I don't know why you need `isEmpty` when you already have `toolsUsed` which you can use it to check if all input are empty.

Lets say if you insist to have `isEmpty`, then you can set it inside input change event.

**The code is not tesed. I wrote the code directly from browser. But you can get the idea before the code.**

```
renderToolsUsed = () => {
  const { toolsUsed } = this.state;
  const tools = toolsUsed.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={i} style={styles.tools}>
         <TextInput value={item.name} onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState({
                toolsUsed: [
                  ...toolsUsed.slice(0, i - 1),
                  {...item, name: text },
                  ...toolsUSed.slice(i)
                ]
             }, this.updateEmptyState)
         }>
         // other input here
      </View>
    );
 });

 // ...
};

updateEmptyState = () => {
  this.setState({
    isEmpty: this.state.toolsUsed.every(x => x.name === '' && x.price === '' && x.count === '')
  })
}
```

Comment: Well, if u check my edit code snippet after writing anything in input it's got error `" cannot read a slice of undefined"`

Comment: @OliverD that's because your state object is defined by `State` and you are later destructuring it from `this.state`

Comment: @OliverD invisal's answer is right you cannot update state like this, it will cause an infinite render.

Comment: @AtinSingh so? it should be `...this.state.toolsUsed.slice` !

Comment: Sorry Guys but to be honest :( when setState `toolsUsed:[...firstOne.slice(),{obj},...second.slice()]` inside `onChangeText` why we use spread operator twice, if anyone can explain thats to me that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The state is not designed to store all the data you have in the app

For what you need isEmpty inside the  state?

To do this, use a global variable

Or check it out when you want it out of the render

Comment: Thanks for the response, can u check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437589/how-to-check-every-item-inside-array) for more info